# Regular Expression in single statement

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "test's t\r and t\n";
str = str.replace(/'/g, "\'");
str = str.replace(/\r/g, "\\r");
str = str.replace(/\n/g,"\\n");
```

Is it possible to do these 3 replaces in single statement?

I want escape these particular chars. With out escaping it makes some problem. "\n" following chars goes to next line. While passing this as parameter it ll not get it as "\n" in the server.

Comment: What language are we talking about? Javascript?

Comment: btw, "tests" has no apostrophe (ie it's not "test's")

Comment: Other answers seem to address your problem. However to get better answers from more people you can give more specific details like: a)Language used b)Is your current code working? c)Sample input, expected output, actual output? d)Add more specific tags based on language, domain, etc.

Comment: ya ok. I thought its regular expression. So that i tagged like that. Will do it properly in future.Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/'|\r|\n/g, function($0) {
    var trans = {"\r":"r", "\n":"n"};
    return "\\" + (trans.hasOwnProperty($0) ? trans[$0] : $0);
})
```

Comment: +1 I forgot replace could take a function as a second argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can also chain them:

```
var str = "test's t\r and t\n";
str = str.replace(/'/g, "\'").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\n/g,"\\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "test's t\r and t\n";
    str = str.replace(/(\'|\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "\\");
    alert("++++++++++++"+str+"++++++++++++");
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. "\n" is to be replaced with "\\n". Perhaps with a forward look-ahead ;-)

Comment: "',n,r" are all missing in the o/p

Comment: u have to modify i can give the flow u have get the food